# Get list of elements from DomParser

Tags: javascript, html, domparser

Alright so here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- head definitions go here -->
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="txtArea"></textarea>
    <button id="btn1" onclick="convertHTML()">
        Analyse
    </button>
    <button id="btn2">
        Clear
    </button>
    <div id="output">

    </div>


    <script>
        function clearTxtArea() {

        }
        function convertHTML() {
            var html = document.getElementById('txtArea').value; //Idk of dit werkt lets see
            var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/xml"); //Zet code om van "<div> fzfhez </div>" etc naar echte HTML elementen
            
            console.log(doc)
            
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And basically I want to turn the data from the txtArea into html elements (so the input would be like `<a>ono<div>test</div></a>` ) and I want my code to loop trough all elements etc and give me a json list of how many a elements and how many div's etc there are displayed

Comment: What is a _"json list"_?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just count the `a` elements user inputted put above your console log this code:

```
const a = document.querySelectorAll("a");

console.log(a.length);
console.log(a); // element list
```